# How to use SVN(subversion) with VCS Gutter plugin in sublime text 3 on windows 7?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, sublimetext3

I am trying to configure tortoise svn with VCS gutter plugin in sublime text 3

I tried adding tortoise svn path in the vcs gutter configuration

```
"vcs_paths": {
    "diff": "diff",
    "git": "git",
    "hg": "hg",
    "svn": "svn"
}
```

I also tried adding path of tortoise svn/bin to environment variable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](https://i.imgur.com/3ppJhiE.png) toolbar button—I've done it for you this time. You also have a preview pane right below the editor so you can see how changes look like before you publish them.

Answer (score 0):

To run this plugin with SVN you need to have both `svn` and `diff` executables on your PATH or in plugin config.

TortoiseSVN has only `svn` tool, but no `diff`. So you need to install `diff` separately (e.g. with [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)). Then add its path to PATH variable or to VCS Gutter's config.